# Address Book crash on iOS10

Tags: addressbook, ios10, abaddressbook

Selecting a contact from contact picker crashes the app in iOS10.0. Contacts picker is shown using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` like this:

```
let contactsPicker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
contactsPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
self.presentViewController(contactsPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the stack trace from crash log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'A property was not requested when contact was fetched.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a1c34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001052cd21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a85265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Contacts                            0x000000010dc6d96f -[CNContact sectionForSortingByFamilyName] + 160
    4   Contacts                            0x000000010dc3e18e __55-[CNContact(iOSABCompatibility) overwritePerson:error:]_block_invoke + 44
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059ad2fd __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 77
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059ad1df -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 207
    7   Contacts                            0x000000010dc3e0f4 -[CNContact(iOSABCompatibility) overwritePerson:error:] + 240
    8   Contacts                            0x000000010dc3dfc0 -[CNContact(iOSABCompatibility) detachedPersonWithError:] + 46
    9   AddressBookUI                       0x00000001057bdd77 -[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController contactPicker:didSelectContact:] + 145
    10  ContactsUI                          0x0000000112396eb2 -[CNContactPickerViewController pickerDidSelectContact:property:] + 306
    11  ContactsUI                          0x000000011243ee6f -[CNContactPickerHostViewController pickerDidSelectContact:property:] + 95
    12  ContactsUI                          0x000000011243f5ec __71-[CNContactPickerExtensionHostContext pickerDidSelectContact:property:]_block_invoke + 66
```

I have already added `NSContactsUsageDescription` in the info.plist as discussed on [Contact Address book crash on iOS 10 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326099/contact-address-book-crash-on-ios-10-beta)  but that didn't help and I can't use `CNContactPickerViewController` as I need to support iOS8 devices.

Comment: Here's answer with lasted Xcode 10 and 4.2 Swift version [CNContactProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650873/address-book-crash-on-ios10/52703420#52703420)

Answer (score 1):

Imran Raheem

From Erdekhayser's solution ([Contact Address book crash on iOS 10 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326099/contact-address-book-crash-on-ios-10-beta))

you can use this method to check CNContactPickerViewController is available?

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"CNContactPickerViewController")) {
        // iOS 9, 10, use CNContactPickerViewController
        CNContactPickerViewController *picker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
        [pr presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        // iOS 8 Below, use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController
        ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        [pr presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Address Book API was deprecated in iOS 9 in favor of the more object-oriented Contacts Framework.

Instead of using the ABPeoplePickerViewController, move to CNContactPickerViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, when I was trying to get an `emailAddresses` from `CNContact` of delegate method.

Initially, I initialize the contactpicker:

```
//MARK: Contact Action
@IBAction func getContactListAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

    vcObject.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Delegate method:

//MAKE: Contact Delegate

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let name = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
    print(name!)
    self.textfieldName.text = name!


    for number in contact.phoneNumbers {

        print("number ----\(number)")

        let mobile = number.value.value(forKey: "digits") as? String
        if (mobile?.count)! > 7 {
            // your code goes here
            print("mobile---\(String(describing: mobile))")
            self.textfieldMobileNumber.text = mobile!
        }
    }


 // this line couse the crash ---> print(contact.emailAddresses[0].value(forKey: "value") as! String)

}
```

I was accessing the email address without declaring in initialization.
Error -- `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'A property was not requested when contact was fetched.'`

CORRECT CODE FOR ACCESSING EMAIL ---

Xcode 10 . and 4.2

```
//MARK: Contact Action
@IBAction func getContactListAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self

    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey] . 
 // <--- Here make declaration for accessing the required property from CNContact.

    vcObject.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

//MAKE: Contact Delegate
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let name = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
    print(name!)
    self.textfieldName.text = name!


    for number in contact.phoneNumbers {

        print("number ----\(number)")

        let mobile = number.value.value(forKey: "digits") as? String
        if (mobile?.count)! > 7 {
            // your code goes here
            print("mobile---\(String(describing: mobile))")
            self.textfieldMobileNumber.text = mobile!
        }
    }


//        print(contact.emailAddresses[0].value.value(forKey: "labelValuePair") as! String)

    for email in contact.emailAddresses {

        print("number ----\(email)")

        let eml = email.value(forKey: "value") as? String
        print("eml --\(eml!)")
    }
}
```